# Pykwalify: Validate data in a dictionary against a yaml file schema

Tags: python, json, yaml, pyyaml

I have python dictionary and a schema.yaml. Is there a way to validate both ? If i dump the dictionary into a yaml file as data.yaml, i can use below code for validation. 
Is there a way to validate schema file with dictionary?

```
from pykwalify.core import Core
c = Core(source_file="data.yaml", schema_files=["schema.yaml"])
c.validate(raise_exception=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found an answer myself. From the pyKwalify  class's source `Core` class accepts `source_data` if no `source_file` is specified.

```
class Core(object):
""" Core class of pyKwalify """

  def __init__(self, source_file=None, schema_files=[], source_data=None, schema_data=None, extensions=[]):
    ...
    ...
    if self.source is None:
        log.debug(u"No source file loaded, trying source data variable")
        self.source = source_data
```

So i can use as-

```
c = Core(source_data=data_dict, schema_files=["schema.yaml"])
```

Comment: Did you mean in your last code line `source_data` instead of `source_file`?

Comment: Right @dougli1sqrd. Corrected. Thanks.